# Ember JS getting object by ID best approach

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am stuck because I'm not sure what is the best way to continue and guides are not so clear about that.

[My Code JSbin](http://jsbin.com/axaqix/2/edit)

Each link displayed is an object obtained from FIXTURE and passed to template, as you can see
I used dynamic segment. 
My purpose is to display, when clicked, an object's properties below the list.

[image]

I'm not sure what is the best way to do it, should I add an action to each link?
I'm quite sure there suppose to be an easier way to when pressed a link to get the item and make it 
appear on screen with all properties but I cannot find the way to do it.

Should I insert another view below the existing view to pass properties to after I got the link
or should I use a different template to display my item when I press the link? keep in mind 
that I want my list to stay visible, this suppose to be one web page application.

To sum it up:

1. How to obtain the object's properties?
2. How to display it on screen on top the opened one? as you can see in the attached image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to insert an `outlet` into your `sites` template where your clicked models data would render it's properties in. And then create a template for it e.g. `sites.site`.

See [here](http://jsbin.com/axaqix/8/edit) for simple working example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Ember, is it correct what I did to render sites template as my main template or should I always use application template as my main?

Comment: @Canttouchit, yes it is ok, you are free to design your app as you please